# Tibco Designer

Tags: xml, jms, tibco, ems, enterprise-integration

I am doing a project with tibco designer and require an xml document to be required to be repeated to 3 destinations with some tags modified. I was thinking of doing this in JAVA with a tokeniser, but I was wondering if TIBCO designer 5.3 has this functionality.

Any Comments or advice will be appreciated.

rgds,
jey

Comment: please elaborate. Do you mean you have an xml document that you need to transform and send to 3 different recipients? What are the details of the transformation you need to perform.

Answer (score 1):

The xml to java transformation could be quite resource consuming.
probably a better approach would be to use 3 times the mapper or sendJms (I'm assuming by 'repeated to 3 destinations' you mean sent 3 times to different jms destinations, if not please provide more details about your project).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a mapper like Daniele said.
If you really need a tokenizer, then you have the tokenize function in the String folder, on the tab "Functions" of the XPath Formula Builder window.

The final approach would be to duplicate you element two times (having it three times) and then surround it with a choice. This is just like the mapper but faster. But for schema restrictions maybe you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send it to 3 different destinations (let's say all are queues) with same tag (let's say tag name as designation) then you have following options:

- 1.A. Use XSLT to transformation (or)
  1.B. Use Mapper and duplicate the designation element and set the condition.

  2. Use JMS Queue Sender
  3. Inside JMS Queue Sender you can dynamically put destination Name in XPath Formula Builder based on the tag you have edit.
  4. Give your JMS Queue Sender correct JMS connection value.

Just make sure the user you will use for this approach, must be same for all 3 destinations in case you will use this approach.